# Why do the squared permanents sum to 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, combinatorics

Consider an  $n^2$ by $n^2$ real [orthogonal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix) matrix $M$.  Let $M'$ be the $n^2$  by $n$ matrix created by selecting the first $n$ columns of $M$.

Now consider all $n$ by $n$ matrices $A_i$ created by selecting exactly $n$ not  necessarily distinct rows from $M'$ *with* replacement.  There are ${n^2+n-1 \choose n}$ such  matricex $A_i$.

Let $s_1,\dots,s_k$ be the number of times each row is selected and let $\tau = \prod_i s_i!$.

As an example, if $n=2$ and $A_i$ is formed by choosing row $1$ twice from $M'$ then $A_i$ will be a $2$ by $2$ matrix with two identical rows.  We have $s_1 = 2$ and $\tau = 2$.

Let $\operatorname{perm}$ be the function that computes the [permanent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent) of a matrix.

Why is the following true?

$$\sum \frac{\operatorname{perm}(A_i)^2}{\tau} = 1?$$

Comment: Are you sure you don't need certain factors in front of the permanents where some rows are sampled several times from $M'$? This would at least result from the permanent Cauchy-Binet formula.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thank you. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Why there are ${n^2 + n - 1 \choose n}$ $A_i$s please?

Comment: @NP-hard It's the number of ways of picking $n$ items from $n^2$ if you are allowed to pick the same items multiple times. See http://www.johndcook.com/blog/select_with_replacement/ for example.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks. I misunderstood your problem. I thought that $A_i$ was generated by sampling a row from $M'$ for each row of $A_i$, and thus $n^{n^2}$.

Comment: Okay, then it does follow from the Cauchy-Binet formula for permanents (Theorem 2 in http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379588901425 ). I don't have a written-out proof anywhere, but it's not much harder than for the usual Cauchy-Binet formula (the only complication is that weakly increasing sequences do not falln away and thus have to be accounted for).

Comment: @darijgrinberg That's interesting. I would love to see a full and self-contained proof as I have never seen one for my specific question.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Do you know how to prove the result using the Cauchy-Binet formula for permanents ? It seems unclear to me why the sum should be 1 exactly I have to admit.

Comment: Just apply it to the permanent of $M'^T M' = I_n $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we were to pick $n$ rows with replacement, but now with order mattering.  In other words, we choose an ordered $n$-tuple of rows $(r_1, r_2, \dots, r_n)$ (since we have $n^2$ choices for each row, there's $n^{2n}$ total ways of picking the rows).  Then for a given $s_1, s_2, \dots, s_k$, the number of ways of picking the rows so that row $i$ is chosen exactly $s_i$ times is then $\frac{n!}{\tau}$.  So in this new framework, we can express the result we're trying to show as

$$\sum_{r_1, \dots, r_n} \textrm{perm}(A)^2 = n!.$$

We can write the permanent as a sum over permutations, i.e.
$$\textrm{perm}(A)=\sum_{\sigma} \prod_{i=1}^n A_{i, \sigma(i)} = \sum_{\sigma} \prod_{i=1}^n M_{r_i, \sigma(i)}$$
When we square $\textrm{perm}(A)$, we can view it as a sum over two permutations, so that the left hand side of the first displayed equation can be written as 
$$\sum_{r_1, \dots, r_n} \sum_{\sigma} \sum_{\tau} \prod_{i=1}^n M_{r_i, \sigma(i)} M_{r_i, \tau(i)} = \sum_{\sigma} \sum_{\tau} \sum_{r_1, \dots, r_n} \prod_{i=1}^n M_{r_i, \sigma(i)} M_{r_i, \tau(i)}$$
The inner sum and product factorize!  We have 
$$\sum_{r_1, \dots, r_n} \prod_{i=1}^n M_{r_i, \sigma(i)} M_{r_i, \tau(i)} = \prod_{i=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n^2} M_{j, \sigma(i)} M_{j, \tau(i)}\right)$$
Now the inner sum is just the inner product between columns $\sigma(i)$ and $\tau(i)$ in $M$.  In particular, if $\sigma(i) \neq \tau(i)$, that inner sum (and therefore the product) is $0$.

If on the other hand, $\sigma=\tau$, then the inner sum is $1$ for every $i$, and the product is equal to $1$.  So each permutation contributes exactly $1$, and the whole sum is $n!$, which is what we're looking for.

Comment: As a side note: There's an old observation due to Turan that if you construct an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ randomly by setting each entry equal to $1$ or $-1$ with equal probability, then the expected value of both $\textrm{det}(A)^2$ and $\textrm{perm}(A)^2$ are equal to $n!$.  The proof's similar -- expand out the squared permanent/determinant as a double sum over permutations, and notice that the "off-diagonal" terms are all $0$ on average.  The difference is that in that case the cancellation is due to symmetry in the entry distributions rather than orthogonality of columns.

Comment: Thank you very much for this clean and complete proof.

Comment: If you select the rows without replacement, so that $\tau = 1$, is there a simple way to estimate the sum? Clearly it will be a number less than $1$ and in my experiments for small $n$ and random $M$ it seems to be near $0.45$.